# How to prevent django from swapping primary key values

Tags: python, django, model

I am creating a Django web app. I have set a field as a primary key and a unique field. When I try to edit it and give it the same value as another item in the primary key column, the current item got duplicated and each value goes to one of them as shown below.

This is my code from `models.py`:

```py
class Car(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Car"
        verbose_name_plural = "Cars"

    car_id = models.CharField(verbose_name='Car ID', max_length=10000, primary_key=True, unique=True)
```

Some screenshots from the admin panel:

[image: FIG. 1]

[image: FIG. 2]

[image: FIG. 3]

[image: FIG. 4]

Comment: You can't change the primary key of a model. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: make your primary key field read-only. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

Answer (score 0):

Once you change the primary key, Django will execute an update statement for that id so corrputing your data, the best way as mentioned by @vishal-singh, is to set the id field as Read-only.